# ¿Como conectar una UWP a una pagina que ofrece servicio de sonido? C#

Tags: c#, uwp

Lo que intento hacer es bajar el sonido de una ip que me proporciono una pagina que brinda el servicio de transmisión de sonido e implementarlo(Reproducirlo) en la app, este proyecto lo comencé en la Plataforma Universal de Windows(UWP), lenguaje C#, espero me puedan ayudar indicándome que puedo implementar, o que temas tengo que revisar en la documentación de Microsoft. De antemano Muchas Gracias.